# Goy eating matzah with treif

Tags: kashrut-kosher, gentiles, matzah

For context, my fiance is a reform convert in the UK. I fully support their conversion but, as I lack any real spirituality, do not feel I could sincerely convert myself (despite knowing that my lack of spirituality would not prevent a reform beit din from accepting my conversion). My fiance doesn't eat pork, but otherwise is fairly lax on kashrut (a position common to many reform Jews here)

We recently celebrated my fiance's first Pesach since converting (during which they observed kashrut more stringently than normal, but, sharing a house with three gentiles, didn't burn all chametz in the house or worry about kitniyot) and had a lot of matzah left over, some KLP (which we used for the seder itself), some not. My fiance actively dislikes eating matzah, whereas I don't mind it. Because of this, and thinking that it's unlikely to last until next year, I've been gradually eating my way through it, breaking it into sections to use like crackers

As a gentile, I am obviously not bound by kashrut (beyond general Noahide prohibitions), but would there be any issue with me combining matzah with treif (i.e. eating salami and cheese on the same fragment)? Does it depend on whether the matzah is KLP and so baked (presumably) with the intent of being used for the mitzvah of matzah in mind?

Comment: RFפ? [charac15]

Comment: @DoubleAA what??

Comment: @AlaychemRememberMonica https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3406/759

Comment: Fyi matzah makes an excellent lasagna base, in some ways better than lasagna noodles. And there is no reason on earth for you not to make a nice meaty matzah lasagna just oozing with bubbly cheese

Comment: Thank you for being so considerate as to ask this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of foods which are *holy* in Jewish law, including:

- Any animal or part thereof dedicated to be a sacrifice, including the Korban Pesach (Paschal lamb)
- Lechem Hapanim ("showbread")
- Mincha offering
- Certain gifts to Kohanim (priests) - Terumah, Terumat Maaser (both from produce grown in Israel), Challah (portion of bread dough prepared by a Jew, normally removed prior to baking)

In addition:

- Shemittah - produce grown in the 7th year of the seven year cycle in the land of Israel may only be harvested and used in certain ways.

For all of the above items, use in any way except for consumption by a Jew, and in some cases very specific Jews (Kohanim, those who are Tahor - ritually pure), is prohibited.

However, from a practical standpoint today, particularly outside of Israel, most of these restrictions are not applicable. There are some exceptions, but generally speaking Matzah, even if baked with the Mitzvah of eating Matzah at the Seder in mind (generally this means hand-made Shmurah Matzah), is simply "food" and has no inherent holiness. There have been issues in some years with Shemittah Etrogim, but as far as I know, commercially sold Matzah is not made from Shemittah grain.

There is a common misconception (I've heard this **many** times myself) that Kosher food (Matzah or otherwise) is "blessed by a Rabbi" to make it Kosher. Rabbis are sometimes involved, but not always, and any blessings involved (e.g., on taking Challah from a batch of dough being baked into Matzah or other bread) do not actually *sanctify* the food.

Comment: Generally, machine-made matzah is also baked with the intent that it be suitable for the fulfillment of the Mitzvah of eating matzah at the seder.

Comment: But baked with that intent doesn't *limit* the usage. A Shevuah or similar vow could have such an effect though, but that isn't normal in a Matzah factory, I hope.

Comment: @IsraelReader I think I misinterpreted your comment - now I see you were saying "**also** machine-made baked with intent". True - though that gets to the whole question of whether "press the starting button" counts as intent in the same way as rolling the dough. But either way, it still doesn't limit the usage.

Comment: Do you have sources to support this? Why should anyone trust your opinion?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't have specific sources at the moment. I am pretty confident in the answer (despite my initially getting Maaser wrong). If anyone wants to write an answer with sources and/or improve my answer, that's fine. The only part that is my "opinion" is the comment about "Kosher food = blessed by the Rabbi" - that's anecdotal (but repeated, many times in many contexts, both from non-Jews and relatively unaffiliated Jews).

Comment: Maaser sheini, bikkurim, hekdesh (doesn't affect the result)

Comment: @Heshy Fee free to add more items to the list in the answer. I should have thought of Bikkurim, since we're almost at Shavuos.

Answer (score 9):

Non-Jews can eat matzah in a shape or from, whenever they want, and with whichever other foods they may choose. (Note Orthodox Jewry does not consider a Reform conversion to be valid.)

All matzah sold in stores has no inherent holiness. Therefore, while they can be used to perform the commandment of eating matzah on the first night of Passover, they can also be eaten during the rest of Passover, when there is no particular command to eat matzah per se (just not to eat chametz). They can also be eaten year round. They can also be consumed by gentiles, and [can even be fed to animals](https://www.toraland.org.il/en/beit-midrash/halachic-guides/around-the-jewish-year/pesach-guidelines-for-feeding-animals/) (Jews are prohibited from deriving any benefit from chametz, on Passover, which precludes feeding their pets chametz [[OC 448:6]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim/448)).

Comment: Do you have sources to support this? Why should anyone trust your opinion?

Comment: The parenthetical about Reform conversion is not relavent to the OP question or to your accurate answer. It would only be relavent if it mattered that a Jew originally bought it or ate some of it. Therefore it is frivolous. The OP came with a considerate question.

Comment: "All matzah sold in stores has no inherent holiness." as opposed to what matzah?

Comment: @Damila Agreed. OP made it quite clear that the question was **not** about the convert, and therefore the question of validity of a particular conversion is not relevant.

Comment: @wfb All matzah "sold in stores" has no inherent holiness, as opposed to the examples provided in the other answer on this page. We can add to the list, the matzos that came along with the "Todah" sacrifice, or matzos that were consecrated as קדשי בדק הבית.

Comment: @Damila I did not intend to be frivolous. However Mi Yodeya is a site for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition. Therefore, in the sake of intellectual honesty, I noted a potential difference of opinion regarding the conversion.

Comment: "sold in stores" - true, Matzah from a Todah (ironically, the Todah also had Chametz, which is why we don't say Mizmor l'todah on Erev Pesach or Chol Hamoed) or a Mincha offering is Kodesh. But **b'zman hazeh** no Matzah is Kodesh (unless one made a vow regarding it or made it Hekdesh) - "in stores" implies "not in stores is different", but homemade Matzah would be the same as "in store" Matzah.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact There is definitely kodesh matza nowadays, namely challah. But that is separated out before it makes it to stores.

Comment: @wfb ^^^^^^^^^^